# How to understand activity with different standard state

Tags: physical-chemistry

There is a description of activity in Wikipedia as below. How shall I understand it? Fox example, I have a solution with pH = 7 ({H+} = 10^-7). The molarity based activity of H+ will be a = 10^-7 (standard state is 1mol/L). However the molar fraction of H+ is 10^-7/55.5 (the 55.5 is the molar of water per liter), which is far away from 10^-7. What is the problem of my understanding? Thanks!

```
The activity is the same regardless of the ways to express composition and the standard state chosen so the above expressions are equal.
```

[image]

Comment: I think that you probably need the mole fraction of $\ce{H^+}$ not water if you standard state is defined via a concentration of $\ce{H^+}$.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks! How shall I correct it? My understanding is the molar fraction of H+ in the solution (H+ and water together) which should be  10^-7/(10^-7+55.5).

Comment: If you *define* the standard state to be pH 7 then the mole fraction of protons is 1, then it changes in a sensible way at pH 6 and 8 etc.